# Problem in sudo apt update with Proton VPN

Tags: apt

Am getting this warnings/errors

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 71EB474019940E11
Reading package lists... Done      
W: GPG error: https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 71EB474019940E11
E: The repository 'https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When I run `sudo apt update`
I searched on google and tried to solve it but nothing worked for me :(

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Go to protonvpn.com and ask them for help/ search there for a GPG-key.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You don't mention any OS & release, but your paste only mentions non-Ubuntu Debian*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From another similar question, I just want to put it here for others as a proper answer that worked for me, too:

I did fix it with this:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and the removed all the proton files in the folder, in my case:

```
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.distUpgrade
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.save
```

Comment: While it does remove the protonvpn repository to stop attempting updates, this answer does not resolve the issue described in the question: `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available` and `Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.` It is presumed that users sharing this issue are seeking to update the repository rather than remove the repository. An appropriate answer would describe how to provide the public key so that updating the repository can be done securely.

Answer (score 3):

Proton's GPG key has long-since stopped working. The simplest way to resolve this is generally to remove ProtonVPN from your source list and re-install ProtonVPN using [the steps on their site](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/).

This is how you can remove the current ProtonVPN repositories:

1. Open "Software & Updates":
   [image: Find Software & Updates]
2. Click the "Other Software" tab:
   [image: Other Software]
3. Find the items that refer to ProtonVPN and uncheck them
4. Press "Close" and, when asked if you want to reload your sources, click on "Reload":
   [image: Reload Sources]

With that out of the way, you can now run your updates without error.

If you would like to continue using ProtonVPN, then you can install it like so:

0. Uninstall the version currently on your computer using [the instructions from ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/)
1. Download the current-release `.deb` package [from the ProtonVPN website](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/)
2. Using Nautilus (or another file browser), double-click the file to have it installed
3. Open Terminal
4. Update apt and install the application again:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install protonvpn
   ```

If there are still questions, the company [suggests getting in touch](https://protonvpn.com/support-form).

Comment: Step 2 doesn't do anything for me. It just opens it like an archive and doesn't install anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short script that solves the situation for Ubuntu based systems following 20.10 update (after `apt-key` and `add-apt-repository` deprecation):

```
curl -fsSL 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x<public-key>' | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/protonvpn-stable.gpg
```

Where `<public-key>` must be replaced with the NO_PUBKEY number displayed in the error message.

Explanation of the curl options:

> ```
>    -f, --fail
>           (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server  errors.  This
>           is  mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with
>           failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP  server  fails  to
>           deliver  a  document,  it  returns  an  HTML document stating so
>           (which often also describes why and more). This flag  will  pre‐
>           vent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
>           This  method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-
>           successful response codes will slip through, especially when au‐
>           thentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).
>
>    -L, --location
>           (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page  has  moved
>           to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a
>           3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the  request
>           on  the  new  place.  If used together with -i, --include or -I,
>           --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown. When au‐
>           thentication  is  used,  curl  only sends its credentials to the
>           initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a different  host,  it
>           won't  be  able to intercept the user+password. See also --loca‐
>           tion-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount  of
>           redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.
>
>           When  curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET
>           (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with
>           a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
>           code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following re‐
>           quest using the same unmodified method.
>
>           You  can  tell  curl to not change the non-GET request method to
>           GET after a 30x response by  using  the  dedicated  options  for
>           that: --post301, --post302 and --post303.
>
>    -S, --show-error
>           When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message
>           if it fails.
>
>    -s, --silent
>           Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don't show progress meter or error mes‐
>           sages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data  you  ask
>           for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect
>           it.
> ```

This gets the public key search results from the keyserver. You can go directly to the [OpenPGP Keyserver](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/) in your browser and search for the public key in question and you'll see it. At this time, it is found at:
https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=4EDE055B645F044F&fingerprint=on&op=index

The results are being piped into gpg which creates a key file at `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/protonvpn-stable.gpg`

Explanation of gpg options:

> ```
>    --dearmor
>           Pack or unpack an arbitrary input into/from an OpenPGP ASCII ar‐
>           mor.  This is a GnuPG extension to OpenPGP and  in  general  not
>           very useful.
>
>    --output file
>    -o file
>           Write output to file.  To write to stdout use - as the filename.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple command to run to update the apt keyring:

```
pv=$(
    curl -s https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-all/ |
        grep -oPm1 '.*">\Kprotonvpn-stable-release_.*_all.deb'
)
curl -Ls "https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-all/$pv" > "$pv"
sudo apt install ./"$pv"
```